How to increase main column width in pkgdown without breaking layout?
I’m trying to increase the width of the main content column in my pkgdown site using the following custom pkgdown/extra.css file:
.row > main {
    max-width: 65rem;
}

This works, but if I go beyond 70rem, the <aside> shifts below the main content, breaking the layout. I suspect this is due to exceeding the container size.
Here’s part of my _pkgdown.yml:
template:
  bootstrap: 5
  bootswatch: simplex
  math-rendering: mathjax
  assets:
    css: ['extra.css']

I’d like a Bootstrap-compliant solution to increase the main column width without breaking the layout. Should I adjust col-* classes or take a different approach? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

